# Mulitline and multiple worklight push notifications

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, ibm-mobilefirst

I have two questions regarding push notifications of IBM MobileFirst hybrid application,

1. How to display a push notifications in multiple line?
2. If we send multiple notifications, last notification will over ride other notifications, how to avoid this?

Testing in android real device.

I am using:

- MobileFirst Version 7.0
- WAS server version 8.5.5.5
- JRE version 1.6

Comment: Hi vivin, am using 7.0

Comment: Hi any solution or any alternate for this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) To enable multi-line Android push notifications -

For details to achieve multi-line notifications, refer to this [blog](https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/blog/2015/11/24/multi-line-gcm-push-notifications-in-android/).

2) To avoid last notification from over riding the previous notifications in Android-

Install the latest ifix, rebuild your application. Edit your wlclient.properties and add the following property-

```
showAllNotificationsInTray=true
```

Comment: Hi Vivin, thank you for your response, tried with the solution for multi-line notification and it works as expected. But need to know is there any way to send multi-line notification using worklight API instead of coding in native java class ?

Comment: At this point , this is not available. You can submit a Request for Enhancement (RFE) here:

https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rfe/

If your question is answered, can you mark it so , please.

Comment: @Vivin  or Idan, regarding second point, i am also facing the same problem with Android devices. I am using the "showAllNotificationsInTray=true" in my wlclient.preoperties file of android application, even though notifications are getting override and only one notification is showing always. 
 And installing ifix version of 7.1 is from Mfp server side, right?

Comment: @RamachandraReddyAvula, the fix mentioned in this case, is client side. Make sure you have the client side fix installed. Also, the change in wlclient.properties ( showAllNotificationsInTray) gets overwritten if you rebuild the environment after generating it. Make sure your properties file still has the value

Comment: @vivin, thanks for your response. Can you please give me the link to download the 7.1 ifix library(i think it is workllight-android.jar, please correct me if not). I was not able to find the link

Comment: @RamachandraReddyAvula, take the latest MFP 7.1 iFix from FixCentral. This is the latest:https://www-945.ibm.com/support/fixcentral/swg/doSelectFixes?options.selectedFixes=7.1.0.0-MFPF-IF201708211241&continue=1

Comment: Now I run the android application by using the library version 7.1.0.0 and added "showAllNotificationsInTray=true" in wlclient.properties file. Still only one notification is showing in notification bar even I send multiple notifications

Comment: @RamachandraReddyAvula, please open a PMR for us to investigate further.